# When does the Gelfand transform map into positive functionals?

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

Let $\mathcal A$ be a unital C* algebra. Consider the Gelfand transform on the unital, commutative C* algebra $\mathcal A_A$ generated by $A$, i.e. $\Gamma: \mathcal A_A \rightarrow C(\mathcal M(\mathcal A_A))$, where $C(\mathcal M(\mathcal A_A))$ are the continous functions on the linear, multiplicative functionals on $\mathcal A_A$.

Now, let $A\in \mathcal A$ be self-adjoint.

What does $\vert\vert \Gamma(A) - \Gamma(\mathbb I)\vert\vert$ have to fulfill for $\Gamma(A)$ to be a positive functional on $\mathcal M(\mathcal A_A)$? For example, is it sufficient that $\vert\vert \Gamma(A) - \Gamma(\mathbb I)\vert\vert\leq 1$ ?

Comment: what is your definition of positive functional on $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{A}_A)$?

Comment: positive on positive elements, so $\Gamma(A)(m^*m)=(m^*m)(A)=m^*(A)m(A)=m(A^*A)=m(A^2)\geq 0, \forall m\in \mathcal M(\mathcal A_A)$

Comment: If $m\in\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{A}_A)$ then $m^*m\notin \mathcal{M}(\mathcal{A}_A)$ in general. So your equalities makes no sense.

Comment: I didn't think about that. Then I want to say that $\Gamma(A)$ is positive iff $\Gamma(A)(m)=m(A)\geq 0$ for all positive $m\in \mathcal M(\mathcal A_A)$, i.e. $m(A)\geq 0 \forall A \in \mathcal M(\mathcal A_A) : A\geq 0$. Would that be properly defined?

Comment: Your definition of positive character now is redundant. If $B\geq 0$, then $\sigma(B)\subset[0,+\infty)$. As I showed earlier in your question $\{m(B):m\in\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{A}_A)\}=\sigma(B)\subset[0,+\infty)$.  Hence all characters are positive in the sence of your definition.